# Converting a Java TCP socket Chat program to a .net C# TCP Chat program

Tags: c#, java, tcp

I have a  Java TCP socket chat I would like to convert to a .net C# program. The code is below...please help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


class Connection
{
    public Socket s;
    public PrintWriter o;
    public BufferedReader i; 
}

class TCPChatServerThreadTask extends Thread
{
    Connection c;


public TCPChatServerThreadTask (ServerSocket serverSocket) throws IOException
{   
    c = new Connection ();

    c.s = serverSocket.accept ();
    c.o = new PrintWriter (c.s.getOutputStream (), true);
    c.i = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (c.s.getInputStream ()));

    System.out.println (c.s.getInetAddress () + ":" + c.s.getPort () + " Connected");

    this.start ();
}   

public void run ()
{
    String fromClient = ">";

    try
    {               
        do
        {           
            fromClient = c.i.readLine ();

            System.out.println (c.s.getInetAddress () + ":" + c.s.getPort () + "> " + fromClient);

            for (int i = 0; i <  TCPChatServerThread.taskCount - 1; i ++)
            {
                TCPChatServerThread.task[i].c.o.println (c.s.getInetAddress () + ":" + c.s.getPort () + "> " + fromClient); 
            }
        }
        while (fromClient != "quit");

        System.out.println (c.s.getInetAddress () + ":" + c.s.getPort () + " Disconnected");

        c.o.close ();
        c.i.close ();       
        c.s.close ();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    } 
}
}

public class TCPChatServerThread
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    static public String str = "?";
    static public TCPChatServerThreadTask[] task = new TCPChatServerThreadTask[10];
    static public int taskCount = 0;
public TCPChatServerThread () throws IOException
{       
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket (4455);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println ("Server: Could not listen on port: ");
        System.exit (1);
    }

    System.out.println ("Server: Listening on port: ");

    while (true)
    {
        task[taskCount ++] = new TCPChatServerThreadTask (serverSocket);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{       
    TCPChatServerThread e = new TCPChatServerThread ();
}
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. Where is your problem?

Comment: i must ask what do you expect here some one to port the code for you?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy that could work:

1. Paste the code in your C# IDE.
2. correct syntax errors
3. Look for errors like unknown class/method xyz
4. Look into the equivalent of the API-Javadoc for c# and look for a c# class/method that is supposed to do the same as the Java-Class, and edit your code accordingly.
5. Test it.

Comment: sorry for the delay I was trying out the advice, which did help in the end..thank you